# Regex to check for two words containing only letters in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex, boolean

This checks for two words but also returns true if words contains numbers. So, How can I to check for two words containing only letters in a sentence with this Regex?

```
Regex.IsMatch(alphabets, @"^((?:\S+\s+){2}\S+).*");
//should return true if string is Honda Civic
//should return false if string is Honda Civic TypeR
//should return false if string is H56da Civic 
//should return false if string is Honda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z][a-z]+\s+` Match an uppercase char A-Z, 1+ lowercase chars a-z and 1+ whitespace chars
- `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match an uppercase char A-Z and 1+ lowercase chars a-z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqwhjs/1)

Or a bit broader, where `\p{Lu}` matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant, `p{Ll}` matches a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant and `[\p{Zs}\t]` matches a whitespace char or a tab.

```
^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+[\p{Zs}\t]+\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+$
```

Example

```
string[] strings = { 
    "Honda Civic",
    "Civic TypeR",
    "H56da Civic",
    "Honda"
    };
foreach (String alphabets in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(alphabets, @"^[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+$"));
}
```

Output

```
True
False
False
False
```